# operator "" _π について

Tags: c++, c++11

N3797([pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf)) の P.309 にある

> ```
> template <char...> double operator "" _\u03C0();
> ```

これの意味がわかりません。
引数が空って、2_π の 2 が無視されるんですか？
それとも _π で使うなら constexpr との違いは？
なぜパラメータパックなんですか？

Answer (score 5):

無視されるわけではなく、_π以前の部分の文字列がcharのパラメーターパックとして渡されます。

例えば、`14142_π`は、`operator "" _π<'1', '4', '1', '4', '2'>()`の呼び出しと同じです。
以下のサンプルでは、パラメーターパックから整数値を復元しています。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

template<typename T>
double decimal(T value) {
    return value - '0';
}

template<typename T, typename... Targs>
double decimal(T value, Targs... Fargs) {
    return (value - '0') * pow(10, sizeof...(Fargs)) + decimal(Fargs...);
}

template <char... T> double operator "" _π() {
    return decimal(T...);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << 14142_π;
}
```

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Z0SiejoGSos13ooN

Comment: 大変参考になりました。
typenameでないパラメータパックの使い途の謎まで氷解し、多謝です。

Answer (score 4):

@h2so5 さんの回答通り、`2`の部分は1文字(`char`型)づつテンプレートのパラメータパックに渡されます。このとき、引数部分は空でなければなりません。(§13.5.8/paragraph 5)

> 5 The declaration of a literal operator template shall have an empty *parameter-declaration-clause* and its *template-parameter-list* shall have a single template-parameter that is a non-type template parameter pack (14.5.3) with element type `char`.

---

> それとも _π で使うなら constexpr との違いは？
>   なぜパラメータパックなんですか？

このコード片は「User-defined literals の識別子(identifier)に、UCN(universal-character-name)が使える」ことを示すことが目的なので、それ以上の意味論を追求しても仕方ない気がします。

Comment: あちゃー、そんな近くに大事なことが書いてあったとは...迂闊でした（笑）　こちらも、良い情報でした。ありがとうございます。